# How to implement smooth responsive parallax effect in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, dom

I have been tasked with creating a landing page for a website. I'm going to be using React, now one of the major things is a parallax effect. When the page first loads, there is navbar at the top (transparent background) but more importantly a header, subtitle and picture that looks like its in the background. As soon as the user begins to scroll down, a parallax effect where basically it zooms out of the picture and transforms it to the right while an image right beside it on the left appears to come in. For a visual example, its something similar to https://pitch.com/ landing page except the second picture looks more separated rather than looking like a part of the picture.

I am wondering how this can be implemented, I started with trying to put the first image in the background but that had a few issues like I wasnt able to fit the picture in the background perfectly, since theres no src set for background-img, but I think the better way would be to have the two images as one image, and somehow when the page loads have it zoomed in on the first pic so that when the user scrolls, the image is scaled and translated to the right? I looked at pitch's code using inspect element it seems like that is what they're doing i think? Is this the best approach and from an implementation stand point with react would i add an event listener for userscroll inside the image component and then pass in a function from App.jsx that handles that?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out react-spring, have a look at their examples here:
https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/examples

Going by your description you should look into interpolating your mouse scroll to the transform property of the image.

Comment: I checked it out, I was kind of confused what is meant by interpolation in this case and so i copy pasted an example into my .tsx file and i got an error saying ``` No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(config: InterpolationConfig<number[], string>): OpaqueInterpolation<string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(x: any, y: any, z: any) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InterpolationConfig<number[], string>'. ``` is this because its tsx and not jsx or js?

Comment: This is pretty confusing man, i've tried to think about how to implement it with custom hooks and i thought maybe i could have a big div and inside have 2 divs, the one on the right would be the initial image and the left would be the second div with second image and form, so initially it would be transformed and translated such that the image on the right fits in the landing page well, then on scroll i'd add an event listed on the window and basically i'd increase or decrease scale and translation by a percentage which would re render screen, would this work? Even so have no clue bout impleme